# Rails: Saving an ordered list with empty values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hypothetical: I want 32 sections with 4 "slots" each. Each slot can hold a person from a draggable list.

What's the best way to save their position (and recall back per user) keeping the spaces or "slots" in the proper place??

Right now, I've got something like the fiddle provided, but upon saving, I'm just sending the `data-id` as an array, so it saves their order, but not taking the empty spaces into account...and of course, my method for reading the list back only returns the array. ie. If I have, upon creation: Tim, empty, Bob, empty my controller saves `['Tim', 'Bob']` and when the user reloads, they see: Tim, Bob, empty, empty

So this is a two sided question:

1) How do I save the user list **including blanks** AND what is the best way to do this with rails/mongoid? *Again, I currently know how to save, I just don't know if its better to use an array/object or what...*

2) How to properly rebuild/read/load the list?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chevinbrown/78kKY/): Imagine that this has 31 other sections to fill...this is just one section.

**EDIT**

If I were to use a gem like `acts_as_list`, would it be bad (since each user will have 128 entries) to have a row per user's item? In my mind, this will make the mongo collection have way too many documents, but I also have a poor understanding of mongodb.

```
user_id, 
pick_id,
position
```

instead of

```
user_id,
picks [
    "pick_id_1234",
    "pick_id_1235",
    "pick_id_1236"
    ]
```

Comment: Are you rendering the view via rails or using a front end framework like Ember.js or Angular.js?

Comment: via rails. I haven't looked into ember or angular, but maybe I should. All of the answers so far aren't really hitting on what I need.

Comment: There is not need to use a front end framework, mongoid and rails is plenty. I'm going to look into your question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Mongoid, so I won't be able to provide specific coding for that part; but I can give you some structural ideas

---

**Saving**

Regardless of *how*, you still need to save the list somehow

Because you've not given enough context, I'll make the assumption you want to maintain the list's state perpetually (using the DB). If you wanted the list to be temporary (I.E you want to move between steps etc), I would recommend [sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions)

**DB**

If you're saving to the DB, the process would be relatively simple. I'll use standard ActiveRecord here, as I don't know mongoid (sorry):

**Models**

```
#app/models/list.rb
Class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :section
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists
end

#app/models/section.rb
Class UserListPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists
    has_many :users, through: :lists
end
```

**Schemas**

```
users
id | name | email | created_at | updated_at

sections
id | details | about | section | created_at | updated_at

lists
id | section_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at
```

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/lists_controller.rb
def new
    @list = 32.times do { List.new } ##needs refactoring
end

def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    @list.save
end

private

def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:section_id, :user_id)
end
```

**Views**

```
#app/views/lists/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @list do |f| %>
    <% Section.all.each do |section| %>
        ##inputs here
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For sanity's sake, wouldn't it be better to have only two db's in the schema? Each user has_many lists, the list could be an serialized object? That's more what I'm getting at and, like I said, I currently have something close to this (I can do MVC), but I don't know how to keep "empty" spaces if a person isn't picked for a slot. Please let me know how I can make my question more clear.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that I already have a the model/controller set up. Each user `has_one` list, and the list `belongs_to` a user. The list is an array of person_ids, which I map on the view load. My main question is, how do I save null values, or keep blanks in the array (because the array order is the user preference, it's not ordered by id DESC)

Comment: Please give me some input here if you can. I think I worded my question in a way that asks *how* to do this...I already have a schema similar to this...

Comment: What you need is to keep all the list elements consistent -- meaning you need to save all 32 slots regardless of whether they have data or not. The best way to do this is to populate a join model, which will save all the list elements, and user positions each time

Comment: I see. Can you speak to whether or not it is better to do this with one collection of "lists" and each list will have embedded docs of the item/position?? Right now it seems like it'd be easier to do that or use a serialized array--but that's only because I'm afraid that this method will make doc sizes larger than necessary.

Comment: Maybe think of it this way: Each user has a list, each list 32 items. I just need to store the position of each item and recall easily. Why is this so difficult to wrap my mind around.

Comment: You just need to keep the list in a table, and have a join model which links `lists` with `users` -- this will allow you to record each lists's position with a user

Comment: So, perhaps it would be best for each item to have a "data-position" attribute to use for the list position??

Comment: You could just use the `id` attribute of the join model (has_many :through) has a primary key for each join model). You could list every `list` item, associate a `user` with each item, and use the `id` as a way to organize them by position :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48406/discussion-between-kevin-brown-and-rich-peck)

Comment: thanks for your input. I've awarded you the bounty...after much consideration, it seems that the best/most efficient solution is to simply use a section class and a list class.

Answer (score 2):

## Assumptions

The object you're assigning to the slots is always the same class, Person.

## Solution

If so then one approach would be to use a simple Struct, since you state it needs to preserve the blanks.

```
# /struct/slotter.rb
Slotter = Struct.new(:section_id, :slot1, :slot2, :slot3, :slot4)

# assuming slots are always the Person#id, i.e. Integer representation 
# of person by their id. Also would work with UUIDs or BSON, etc. 
# The section number would be stored in the variable *section_no*
Slotter.new(section_no, id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4)

# You can also pass a block to a Struct  so you could write read
# accessors for the data, again this assumes Person class exists
Slotter = Struct.new(:section_id, :slot1, :slot2, :slot3, :slot4) do 

  def read_slot1
    Person.find(slot1)
  end

end
```

The file system is independent of this as this will give you an object that has a proper Marshal.dump and load so you can save or load from any database you wish.

Since your app is using Javascript, you can convert it to JSON as it has a proper to_json if used in a Rails app. Or write a to_json if you need different root nodes, etc.

## Side thoughts

This problem is essentially a bitmask problem. If you can reformat your problem, you could probably just create a integer column and store the data with your Person class in a simple Integer column.  I'll leave you to figure out that one. :)

Also this app is probably better as a JavaScript app, say in Angular.js, with a Rails backend to persist into the database. This way you'll be able to modify a giant JSON object on the fly in the Client, and the load will be kept off of your server.

### Update

regarding bitmask approach. This is one way to do use a Plain Old Ruby Object to wrap/unwrap the bitmask as an integer. Its based loosely on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association?view=asciicast).

[This particular approach](https://gist.github.com/nacengineer/9301156) only leverages the bitmask to store a section's slots values. The same approach could be applied to store up to n values though. The key is that the SLOTS array is essentially always the same. You can add to the right side, e.g. slot5 to the right of slot4, but can't change the order of it.

### Update #2

#### Bitmask Limitations

The main limitations are

- **complexity** of wrapping/unwrapping (which as you can see isn't that
  hard)
- **static slots array** the array that controls the bitmask can only be added to. i.e. You can't change the order of existing entries you can only add more to the end.

The side benefit is you can store a heckuva a lot with only an integer which more than compensates IMO. So if you want to get all the players that have x attribute set you'll need a method such as:

```
def in_slot?(slot)
  slots.include?(slot.to_s)
end
```

You'd still be able to get the stats you'll just have to do it in code vs SQL. i.e. map over the array (in ruby). As such:

```
all.keep_if {|p| p.is_slot?(:slot1)}
```

But if you know the mask of what you're looking for, eg. in the example we want all slot1 and slot3 then we know that mask is *5* so you just look up all entries with a slots_mask of 5.

If down the road you find that you need more advanced functionality i.e. the management of the mask solution is slowing you down more than storing your values in SQL. You can always unwind your mask into a new solution, say serialize or more formal subclasses, with a quick map over the Array of object.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. What I'm most interested in at the moment is what structure would be best. 128 docs per user, or one doc with a hash field of 128 picks? I like the hash method because it seems more concise...but I'm not sure how to use hashes very well.

Comment: I think you need a Struct because its a lightweight class that gives you a predefined structure and essentially the thing you're looking for, managing the nil unset slots. However I think the greater issue is if you think of the section/slot as switches, then with a bitmask that unwraps a simple integer, one 7-bit unsigned integer would give you the 128 possible values. You could also do simple bit masks on each Section with a 2-bit unsigned integer. If you have your heart set on Hashes, maybe use an OpenStruct as you can instantiate it with a Hash and can pass a block to unwrap the Bitmask.

Comment: You're over my head...I'm new to CS and novice/intermediate level with rails. Can you provide some resources for me to ready?

Comment: Right now I've got a working model where I create 128 records with `player_id: "null"` and let the user fill in as appropriate. But again, each document takes up much more space in mongodb than needed b/c I don't need the fields `_id, created_at, updated_at`...

Comment: No problemo. I've updated my answer to show a working example with a PORO (plain ol' Ruby Object). Struts work a little differently so I stuck with the simplest object I could create. A PORO should be light weight enough. If using this in rails obviously you can add the database specific stuff.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you are using Mongo? Unless its a project requirement, as you're new to Rails/programming Mongo might be a little harder as its a NoSQL DB. There is nothing in your problem, as described, that precludes you from using a traditional DB such as Postgres. The documentation is much more through and the database itself will be easier to work with for you, i.e. you can do a SQL dump/reload. Having said that your problem isn't database constrained. Essentially you could do it all in the browser with JavaScript and persist into the DB when needed.

Comment: Mongo is easier for me since I don't have to worry about migrations...but it's also a poor excuse for being lazy. Before I award, I'd like to know what the limitations of using a bitmask would be. ie. if I want stats on which player was picked most for x position?

Comment: I'm sorry for being slow. Considering doc size and speed, would it be good to avoid hashing/arrays for 128 entries per user, or is it ok to have one doc per pick per user?

Comment: I like the idea of Structs, but I still don't totally get it. (Also haven't had time to review completely).

Comment: Structs are light weight ruby classes you predefine. They use Hash's Fast Mapping for fetching variables. But you don't need hash keys as you've predefined them. You just pass the variables in the predefined order. If you need more than that OpenStructs move beyond basic Structs by allowing you to instantiate them with a Hash. If you need more than that... you create a Class. Basically Structs give you a lot of Class functionality but are built into ruby. So you get essentially a Class with accessors with a one-liner.

Comment: Ok, so speaking from an efficiency perspective, this would be best. (rethink this a bit) Each user has 32 "slots" and each slot 4 documents...this seems to be best as I can present a "slot" and paginate to the next "slot" via json/ajax, and update via serialization?

Comment: Also, a struct can be easily expanded to a class if needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two parts to your problem: 1. You need to store the various lists for each section on the front end 2. Then store those lists in your DB in a way the preserves all the data (including the blanks) so you can recreate the same view in the future.

I'll try to answer each part separately and then give you an idea of how they come together.

Now onto a solution!

**Front End**

What I recommend doing is maintaining a JSON object in the view that contains the values of all the picks (whether its null or filled in). So I made some changes to your fiddle  to give you a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/3SSqM/41/ (My apologies, some of the code in here is not very robust, and its really not good practice to store a variable on windows.document, but I was just trying to whip up something quick that would demonstrate how this works). Here is what is worth noting from the fiddle:

- Each section is given an id of the format 'picks-group-NUMBER'
- There is a JS object called `indexes` that maintains the list of all picks, each key is an id from 0-127, so the 1st slot in the 1st section has an id of 0 and the fourth slot in the 32nd section has an id of 127
- When the dragging event is finished you can get the section name (ie extract the NUMBER from the table id) and then populate the JS object with the data-id of all the picks. The way I think you should do this is as follows:

  ```
   $('.picks-group').sortable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    start: // some code
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        sorting = false;
        sectionNumber = getSectionNumber($(this)[0].id);
        $(this).find('li').each(function (i, obj) {
            var index = sectionNumber + i;
            indexes[String(index)] = $(obj).attr('data-id');
        });
    },
    change: // some code
  });
  ```

Notice that this will preserve the 'nulls' which is exactly what you want. When the user is done making picks, you can send the `indexes` JSON object to Rails which should be pretty simple. Use the JSON parser in rails to convert the JSON object into a hash.

**Back End**

Now the way you store this data in Mongoid is another interesting problem. This really depends on how you intend to use the data. If all you plan to do is store the data until the next time the user visits your web app and then rerender his/her picks, then I would go ahead and store the entire object as one attribute thats a hash. Something like:

```
Class Pick
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :picks, type: Hash

end
```

So simple! Don't you just love mongoid?

But if you were planning on querying the data, like trying to find out who the top picks were, then this might not be ideal. Now the possibilities are quite vast, the schema really depends on what your use cases are, here are a few considerations:

- Do you want to run analytics on the data in your own time for your own use? In that case you could still store it in a hash and run a map reduce on your data.
- Do you need real time analytics, in which case using map reduce might not be ideal. I would break down the data a little more depending on what granularity you need to query at.

So if you need to know who is the most popular pick for the first section in the first slot you could do something like:

```
Class Pick
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :pick_0
  field :pick_1
  # ... you get the idea
  field :pick_127

end
```

BTW, don't actually list out each attribute from pick_0 to pick_127, I just did that to give you an idea of what I meant, if you want to go down this path use dynamic attributes as described here: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields

**Rerendering Views**

And the last thing you were curious about: how can you recreate the views the next time the user logs in. Well this depends on how you stored the data, but lets say you stored the entire thing as a hash, in the view you just iterate over all the different key-value pairs stored in the hash and render your tables. This part should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you. Dynamic fields are sounding good...sounds like using a hash would be too limiting? Can you speak at all to using Structs? If I want to paginate all records and show ever 4 like my fiddle, how would you recommend doing that (with placeholders showing point value)?

Comment: Structs are great for structured data and there are a few blog posts that describe the tradeoffs (heres one: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/017-Struct.html). If you are going to use structs then the schema described by @engineerDave great. I personally would rather put each section in its own class and give each Section an attribute for each of the 4 slots. Then one way to display that data would be by creating a view for a single section and by navigating to a url like app.com/section/:id, render that section. Maybe you can tell me more about how you plan to use this?

Comment: It's basically like a fantasy draft. 32 teams, each team gets 4 guesses. So I guess you're right. I should have a `Team` class, each team has_many :picks, and each `Pick` has_many (4) :players.

Comment: That sounds good actually. I prefer the schema you suggested to a struct/hash because its flexible enough that its easy to create a view for a single section as well as being able to show all the sections that a user makes

Comment: And it won't make things difficult/make too many db calls to have them split into teams as opposed to one call for all 128 picks?

Comment: Well there are two things I would say: First, I'm sure you've heard "premature optimization is the root of all evil". You should try it one way, see if DB calls are really an issue based on your current usage, and if not, worry about that at a later date when it does become an issue. Secondly, in this case it would make sense to use embedded records (again, this is a huge advantage of mongoid!). So Team embeds Picks. This way, when you load a team, you load all the picks in the same DB call.

Answer (score -1):

Save the list as an array of User IDs. Using Mongodb, this array would usually be embedded in the user document.

Either stuff the array with `null`s to represent the blank spaces, so Tim, empty, Bob, empty becomes `['Tim', null, 'Bob', null]` in JS/Mongodb or save position IDs with the user IDs so you have `[[0, 'Tim'], [2, 'Bob']]`. Which one is more efficient depends on how many slots, on average, are left blank. Using `null`s is probably going to be easier, so I'd favor it, all else being equal.

Comment: If each user has 128 picks, an array of 128...would that be slow or difficult to run analytics on?

Comment: Mongodb is a JSON document store; it's not optimized for analytics the way a SQL database is. In particular, it lacks a `JOIN` capability, so splitting data into multiple collections kill your analytics performance. Storing picks in an array is probably the most efficient way for Mongodb to do what you are asking.

Comment: Good info. The issue I was running into is that when I queried, it would return entries sorted by the player_id, instead of the order in which the array was stored AND it would discount/remove the nulls.